# ld: file not found: libkobold2d-ios.a (Kobold2d)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I am having a problem when trying to build to my device. I keep getting the error:

```
ld: file not found: /Users/Stephen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tire_Hoops-buzmngpjbdxukpbanrmqlxpfbreg/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libkobold2d-ios.a
```

I saw on the kobold2d 1.0.4 release page in the comments that people were having this problem, and from what I could see it had to do with the these lines in the build settings.

FORCE_LOAD_COCOS2D = -force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libcocos2d-ios.a
FORCE_LOAD_KOBOLD2D = -force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libkobold2d-ios.a
FORCE_LOAD_COCOS3D = -force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libcocos3d-ios.a

I am wondering if there is a fix for this, because I cannot build in release mode without fixing this.

Comment: I am at a loss to know what to do

Comment: try kobold 2.0 to see if it makes any difference. If it's a new project definitely use 2.0, there's no point in supporting 1st/2nd gen devices anymore.

Comment: It's not a new project and I have already tried using 2.0 and there were just to many complications to switch it over.

Comment: Is there no way that I can fix this?

Comment: Have you read this? http://www.kobold2d.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=919841  Most common cause is to open two Kobold2D workspaces (of the same directory) at once.

Comment: I have read that and I have tried everything that was suggested and nothing works. The only thing that does away with the error is to copy all of the .a files from the debug build to the release build, but then if I clean my project it deletes all of them and I have to add them again.